# Foundation 5 Accordion with vertical tabs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

Im trying to add vertical tabs in accordion in Foundation 5. So, what I did I just copied the code from http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/accordion.html and changed the tab type to vertical:

```
<dl class="accordion" data-accordion>
  <dd>
    <a href="#panel1">Accordion 1</a>
    <div id="panel1" class="content active">
      <dl class="tabs vertical" data-tab>
        <dd class="active"><a href="#panel2-1">Tab 1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#panel2-2">Tab 2</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#panel2-3">Tab 3</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="#panel2-4">Tab 4</a></dd>
      </dl>
      <div class="tabs-content vertical">
        <div class="content active" id="panel2-1">
          <p>First panel content goes here...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content" id="panel2-2">
          <p>Second panel content goes here...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content" id="panel2-3">
          <p>Third panel content goes here...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content" id="panel2-4">
          <p>Fourth panel content goes here...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </dd>
  <dd>
    <a href="#panel2">Accordion 2</a>
    <div id="panel2" class="content">
      Panel 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </dd>
  <dd>
    <a href="#panel3">Accordion 3</a>
    <div id="panel3" class="content">
      Panel 3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

What I get is:
[image]

Any idea why it doesnt scale with tabs but rather with text??? And ofc how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the script.

```
$(document).foundation();
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/7Rp5C/3/
See the jsfiddle example live here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/7Rp5C/3/show/

The provided CSS does not clear the floats when using vertical tabs in accordions

Just do to clear the floats:

```
.accordion .content { overflow: hidden; }
```

or

```
.accordion .content:before,  
 .content:after {  
  content: " ";  
  display: table;  
}  
.accordion .content:after {  
   clear: both;  
}
```

Comment: I do invoke it and now try with vertical attribute  <div class="tabs-content vertical">. It doesnt work.

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/7Rp5C/2/ - I added the class on the dl ( <dl class="tabs tabs vertical" data-tab>) works for me. Check the source for what css and js dependencies I included or the external resources in js fiddle.

Comment: Now I see you need to clear the panel content containers http://fiddle.jshell.net/7Rp5C/3/show/ - You can do:
.accordion .content {
    overflow: hidden;
}